# Retrieve the date from a string path

Tags: string, awk, sed, grep

I have a for loop that recursively searches a directory for files.

```
for FILE in $(find /home/mydir/ -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.zip')
```

They have the following format:

```
/home/mydir/subdir1/subdir2/22280317.txt
```

I want to extract the 6 numbers left of the `.txt` as the date in the format `2017-03-28` I've tried using `awk` however am having trouble as there are two digits at the start that I want to ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'f=${0%.txt}; l6=${f: -6}; date -d  "${l6: -2}-${l6:2:2}-${l6:0:2}" +"%Y-%m-%d" '  {} \;
```

**Test Results**

```
# create sample files
[akshay@localhost test]$ touch 10280317.txt 
[akshay@localhost test]$ touch 10170317.txt 
[akshay@localhost test]$ touch 10170398.txt 

# files created
[akshay@localhost test]$ ls *.txt
10170317.txt  10170398.txt 10280317.txt

# output using date command which takes care of year
# remove .txt
# extract last 6 char
# input year-mon-date to date command
[akshay@localhost test]$ find -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'f=${0%.txt};  l6=${f: -6};  date -d  "${l6: -2}-${l6:2:2}-${l6:0:2}" +"%Y-%m-%d" '  {} \;
2017-03-28
2017-03-17
1998-03-17
```

In case if you want to display filename along with date then

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ pwd
/tmp

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ find -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'f=${0%.txt};  l6=${f: -6}; echo $f $(date -d  "${l6: -2}-${l6:2:2}-${l6:0:2}" +"%Y-%m-%d") '  {} \; 
./tss/test/10280317 2017-03-28
./tss/test/10170317 2017-03-17
./tss/test/10170398 1998-03-17
```

Answer (score 0):

With ***sed*** expression:

```
find /home/mydir/ -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.zip' | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\.txt/20\3-\2-\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are allways named in the same format (22280317.txt) this is my solution:

```
awk -v FPAT="([0-9]{2})" 'BEGIN{ FS = "/"; OFS = "-" }{ x = substr($NF, 3, 6);  if (patsplit(x, a)) print a[1], a[2], "20"a[3] }'
```

prints:

```
28-03-2017
```